# Laplace transform of the following function

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

find the laplace transform of the function :

$$f(t) =\begin{cases}
t^2,  & 0<t<1 \\
2\cos t+2, & t>1  \\
\end{cases}$$

My attempt:

$$L\{f(t)\}=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-st} \ t^2 \ \text{d}t+\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-st} \ (2\cos t+2) \ \text{d}t$$

Now,
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{-st} \ t^2 \ \text{d}t=\frac{-1}{s}e^{-s}-\frac{2}{s}te^{-s}-\frac{2}{s^3}e^{-s}+\frac{2}{s^3}$$

And

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-st} \ (2\cos t+2) \ \text{d}t$$

But the integration is not stopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \int_1^{\infty} dt \, e^{-s t} \cos{t} &= \Re{\left [\int_1^{\infty} dt \, e^{-(s-i) t} \right ]}\\ &= \Re{\left [\frac{e^{-(s-i)}}{s-i} \right ]}\\ &= e^{-s} \Re{\left [(\cos{1}+i \sin{1}) \frac{s+i}{s^2+1}\right ]} \\ &= \frac{s \cos{1}-\sin{1}}{s^2+1} e^{-s} \end{align}$$

$$ \int_1^{\infty} dt \, e^{-s t} = \frac{e^{-s}}{s}$$

Multiply by $2$, add, done.

Comment: Would you please tell how $\cos t=e^{it}$?

Comment: @user2983722: Real part.  That's the meaning of the $\Re{}$; sorry that was not clear.

Comment: $ \int_1^{\infty} dt \, e^{-s t} = \frac{e^{-s}}{s}$??

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Besides to @Ron's post, you can use the following fact:

> If $$f(x)= \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             f_1(x) & \quad 0\le x \leq a \\
>             f_2(x) & \quad x \ge a
>         \end{array}
>     \right.$$ then it can be written as $f(x)=f_1(x)+(f_2(x)-f_1(x))u_a(x)$ in which $u_a(x)$ is [step function](http://www.math.psu.edu/srikrish/math251/notes/stepfunctions.pdf).

Of course $\mathcal{L}(u_a(x))=\frac{e^{-as}}{s}$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Good time Sami. Glad to see you on the site :-)

Comment: Yes, a nice observation! =1

Answer (score 1):

Integrals like $\int e^{-st}\cos(t)dt$ are circular and are handled as follows.  First set
$$F(s) = \int e^{-st}\cos(t)dt$$
Now using by parts with $u = e^{-st}$ we get
$$F(s) = e^{-st}\sin(t) + s\int e^{-st}\sin(t)dt$$
(assuming $s > 0$ for the limit).  Then do by parts again with $u = e^{-st}$ again and get
$$F(s) = e^{-st}\sin(t) + s\left(-e^{-st}\cos(t) - s\int e^{-st}\cos(t)dt\right) = e^{-st}\sin(t) -se^{-st}\cos(t) - s^2F(s)$$
So to finish solve
$$F(s) = e^{-st}\sin(t) -se^{-st}\cos(t) - s^2F(s)$$
for $F(s)$.

Comment: The point is not the bounds, the point is to teach how to do the integral.

Comment: I was expecting you simply to say, "Whoops, sorry, fixed."  But I guess I should apologize to you for having the nerve to point out an error in your posting.

Comment: You don't have to apologize for pointing out an error, but you also don't have to be rude if *I* point out that teaching someone how to do the problem without explicitly giving them the answer is a good thing.

Comment: The tone of my response is a reflection of yours.  You can choose to react in any way to criticisms of your work.  But telling me that mistakes don't matter - or are not the point - is IMO a poor choice.  Getting it right is the point.  And as you got it right, this discussion is moot.